# When is salary usually paid in software development companies in Germany?

Tags: salary, germany, payroll

Is there a specific norm that most of the software development companies in Germany follow in regards to the date of salary payment for full-time employees? There is no specific day stated in my work contract and I heard some people (not my colleagues) say that it's mostly 'end of the month'. What does this mean? Last working day of the month?

Comment: Most countries have standards that govern payment but very rarely does that include a particular time of the month (it's more about X days after the first work day in a cycle, once monthly, ...). If you specifically want to know when *you* will be paid it's faster to just ask your payroll / HR team.

Comment: Also, if this is the first time you're getting paid by them, there may be additional delays. That's why you should really talk to them.

Comment: I also get my salary by the "end of the month". That's normal.

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with software development?

Comment: During my whole career, the policy in each company was always the same: at the end of the month. But keep in mind that this is not an exact date. Usually, this means that you can be expected to be paid around the 28th-30th. But I once worked for a company that never paid before the 3rd of the next month. Be prepare to be able to deal with it when that happens.

Answer (score 9):

"End of month" means some (typically 1 to 3) working days before the last day of the month. This is to go sure that you have your money at the last day of month* since many regular payments (rent, insurances, loan payments, etc) are due at the first working day of the month.

Some companies also pay mid-month (with the 15th as due date), but with the same scheme, i.e. some days prior to the actual payment day.

*Although handled digitally, bank transfers in Germany still often take one working day, so you want some time buffer.

Comment: To add onto this, you can contact your accounting/payroll department and ask questions like this too. Specifc dates or just a general timeline. It's not rude and they're in a direct position to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually around the 24th, due to some other (government instances) payouts this has become the norm. Add some additional delays if the transfer is between different banks.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact HR and ask them whether they have a list of payout dates for the year. At my current employer payout dates range from the 23rd to the 26th due to weekends and bank holidays, but they typically sent the list early in the new year.